# To find expected value after performing some operations on array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, expectations, range-query

I find problems in solving these kinds of questions

Suppose there is an array A[1....n] and we can perform two kinds of operations on the array:

1. Randomly Select Two Indexes p and q with p < q then swap A[p] with A[q]
2. Randomly Select Two Indexes p and q with p < q then reverse (A[p...q]) (Both Inclusive)

After performing the first operation 'a' times and the second operation 'b' times, we randomly choose two indices p & q with p < q and calculate the S = sum(A[p...q]) (Both Inclusive).

Now, we have to find the expected value of S.

Given Inputs are n,a,b,A[1....n]

How to do so ??

Comment: Work through some simple examples with pencil and paper.  Write some code.  Think about what you have learned and see if you can extract some general rules from the specific examples. We all *find problems in solving these kinds of questions* but those of us who work them out become programmers, the rest of you are doomed to asking this sort of question on SO.

Comment: at least tell us what your thoughts are? brute force? Linearity of expectation? anything?